# Using jquery custom widgets with backbone.js views

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, jquery-widgets

I have a custom jQuery widget that is being called from my app that uses backbone.js for MVC. How can I use the backbone events pattern in my custom jQuery widget?

```
function( $ ) {
  $.widget( "medex.chooser", {
  ...
  _create: function() {
      // Would I create a new backbone view here???
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create the view normally but give it the widget's `element`: `new View({ el: this.element })`?

Comment: Thanks but I want the custom widget to handle the events.

Comment: So is the widget the view? The widget contains the view? The view contains the widget? Or something else?

Comment: That was my question. Should the widget contain the view? The widget basically lays out 2 jqgrids side by side and allows users to move rows from one to another. I was wondering if there is a best practice to create a view within the widget --  maybe I am over thinking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define a custom View that is then called by your custom widget.

In your app initialization code, for example:

```
APP = {};          // your app's global object
APP.Views = {};

APP.Views.WidgetView = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    events: {
        "click .grid1" : "onGrid1Click"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // code here
    },

    onGrid1Click : function(evt) {
        // code here
    }
});
```

Then this will be the constructor code for your widget:

```
function Widget(element) {
   this.view = new APP.Views.WidgetView({ el: element });
}
```

This code might not be entirely valid, but should give you an idea of the structure you were looking for.  Lemme know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for an answer, you could convert a widget into a view.
The basic rules for converting from a Widget to a View are these:

- _create becomes initialize
- this.element becomes this.$el
- refresh becomes render
- destroy becomes remove
- $('.someDiv').myWidget() becomes new MyView({ el: $('.someDiv') });
- options have to become constructor parameters, but can be handled a couple of different ways